# Not able to find Done in mocha test cases using Chai-http

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

I'm learning to write test cases using mocha and chai for the node application,I had written the below test case

```
let chai = require('chai');
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

const should = chai.should;
const expect = chai.expect;
const server = "http:\\localhost:3000"

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Create Login and Register', () => {
    it('should login using credentials', () => {
        chai.request(server)
            .get('/register')
            .send()
            .then((res: any) => {
                res.should.have.status(200);
                done();
            }).catch((err: any) => { done(err) })
    })

})
```

but it shows the read swiggle below the done(); function
[image]

do i need to add some types for it to get working what is that i'm missing ,i tried to install chai-http again but still same issue

Comment: That's because you're not using the `done` parameter from your `it` call back... change it to look like `it('..', done => { /* your stuff */ done() });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`done` is passed in as the first argument to your test function.

```
describe('Create Login and Register', () => {
    it('should login using credentials', (done) => { // <-- here
        chai.request(server)
            .get('/register')
            .send()
            .then((res: any) => {
                res.should.have.status(200);
                done();
            }).catch((err: any) => { done(err) })
    })
})
```

Although, because you are using a `Promise` chain, you should just return the chain instead.

```
describe('Create Login and Register', () => {
    it('should login using credentials', () => {
        return chai.request(server)
            .get('/register')
            .send()
            .then((res: any) => {
                res.should.have.status(200);
            }); // a rejected promise will fail the test automatically
    })
})
```